# Why is my restful Angular route always re-routing to the default route?

Tags: angular, rest, routes

Trying to trying to figure out with Angular 11 how to set up a route with a restful parameter.  I have this in my src/app/app.module.ts file

```
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
    UserComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    // core & shared
    SharedModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MatTableModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, 
    MatPaginatorModule, 
    MatToolbarModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and then in my src/app/app-routing.module.ts, I have

```
const routes: Routes = [
  //{ path: "", redirectTo: 'hot', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: "hot", component: HotComponent },
  { path: "latest", component: LatestComponent },
    ...
  { path: "user/:username", component: UserComponent },
];
```

However, when I restart my app, and I visit http://localhost:4200/user/myusername, I'm redirected to http://localhost:4200/#/, without my component attempting to be rendered.  Is there some other way I should be setting up a restful route in my Angular routing module?

Comment: I've always used "/:id" I never knew that to be a requirement but try replacing "user/:username" with "user/:id"

Comment: As a simple debugging step I would move the definition of the route to the top of the Routes array. Order matters . If that resolves your issue then it's simply another route definition confusing the Router

Comment: Not sure why, but the URL http://localhost:4200/#/user/myusername brings up the page I was looking for.